# When is __package__ not present?

Tags: python, python-import

PEP366 states:

> The major proposed change is the introduction of a new module level attribute, `__package__`. When it is present, relative imports will be based on this attribute rather than the module name attribute.

Will it ever be the case that it is not present? I know it can be `None`, `''`, or `__name__.rpartition('.')[0]` but, will it ever be that referencing `__package__` will throw me an attribute not found error? Is it safe to say that `__package__` is always present actually?

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/4c14b5de1cf372e963a4378fc6cb2bca36d24eb8